# What happens to carbon deposits in car engines when heated?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to determine the characteristics of carbon deposits in a gasoline automobile engine.

Will the carbon deposits in and around the cylinders of an automobile engine

1. soften,
2. harden, or
3. remain unchanged

when the engine heats up to it's normal operating temperature?